# How do I select a specific sub-node of an XML file using XML::Twig?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I have an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<!DOCTYPE tmx SYSTEM "56.dtd">
<body>
<tu changedate="20130625T175037Z"">
  <tuv xml:lang="pt-pt">
    <prop type="x-context-pre">&lt;seg&gt;Some text.&lt;/seg&gt;</prop>
    <prop type="x-context-post">&lt;seg&gt;Other text.&lt;/seg&gt;</prop>
    <seg>The text I'm interested.</seg>
  </tuv>
  <tuv xml:lang="it">
    <seg>And it's translation in italian.</seg>
  </tuv>
 </tu> 

 .... followed by other <tu>'s
</body>
```

Since it's a huge file, I'm using `XML::Twig` to parse it and get the parts I'm interested in. I'm particularly interested in `seg`'s node content as well as `tu`'s node attribute.

Here's the code I've got so far:

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $filename = 'filename.tmx';
my $out_filename = 'out.xml';
open my $out, '>', $out_filename;
binmode $out;

my $original_twig = new XML::Twig (pretty_print => 'nsgmls', twig_handlers => {tu =>   \&original_tu});
$original_twig->parsefile($filename);

sub original_tu {
    my($twig, $original_tu) = @_;
    my $original_seg = $original_tu-> first_child('./tuv/seg')->text;
   
}
```

Perl (or should I say `XML::Twig`) tells me that I've got:

```
wrong navigation condition './tuv/seg' ()
```

Does anyone know how to access the `seg` node's text and how to access the `changedate` attribute of `tu`'s node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to access that node and attribute:

```
my $original_seg = $original_tu->first_child('tuv')->first_child('seg')->text;
my $date = $original_tu->att('changedate');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a complete XPath expression with `first_child`, just a single XPath step (ie you can only go down 1 level).

To use an XPath expression you need to use `findnodes`:  `my $original_seg = $original_tu->findnodes('./tuv/seg', 0)->text` (the `,0` gets the first element of the (potential) list of hits.

To access an attribute, use `$original_tu->att( 'date')`

Answer (score 0):

The condition used in `first_child` cannot use XPath. See https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Twig#cond for details. The method would have been misnamed if it did - `first_child` returns a child, but `seg` is a grandchild of `tu`.

You can use `first_descendant('seg')` instead.

To access the attribute, use the `$original_tu->att('changedate')` method.